# List orders via Woocommerce Rest API

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Im trying to list all orders or the latest 100 orders in my shop via woocommerce rest api v2.

I have installed there official framework from https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library

And i got it working to list all customers i have with:

$customers = $woocommerce->get('customers');

But when i try to list all orders per there documentation

$orders = $woocommerce->get('orders');

i get an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException: The decoded property name is invalid in /home/xxx/xxx/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/HttpClient.php:375 Stack trace:
#0 /home/xxx/xxx/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/HttpClient.php(414): Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient->processResponse() 
#1 /home/xxx/xxx/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/Client.php(82): Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClient->request('orders', 'GET', Array, Array) 
#2 /home/xxxx/xxxx/index.php(27): Automattic\WooCommerce\Client->get('orders') 
#3 {main} thrown in /home/xxxx/xxxx/vendor/automattic/woocommerce/src/WooCommerce/HttpClient/HttpClient.php on line 375
```

Comment: Did you try $woocommerce->orders->get(); ?

Comment: Thank you for response but did not work.

Comment: Looking at error, it seems issue is not with the request, but with the response. Did you try fetching only one order by ID?

Comment: Getting same error with it. Its odd that get customers work just fine.

Comment: But you are right its issue with the reponse will make a bug report to the framework insted. thanks!

Comment: protected function get_parsed_response 
in /lib/woocommerce-api/class-wc-api-client-http-request.php
is responsible for decoding... you can check by directly print_r or by returning unparsed results.